# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails tables empleado and contrato

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I get this error when perform an insert query:

```
 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`unimonito`.`empleado`, CONSTRAINT `empleado_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cargo`) REFERENCES `cargo` (`idCargo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

My tables are:

```
 CREATE TABLE `contrato` (
  `idContrato` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `tipoContrato` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fechaInicio` date NOT NULL,
  `fechaFin` date NOT NULL,
  `cedulaEmpleado` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `empleado` (
  `idEmpleado` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nombreEmpleado` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cargo` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `taller` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `franquicia` (
  `idFranquicia` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nombreFranquicia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `taller` (
  `idTaller` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nombreTaller` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Franquicia` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `contrato`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idContrato`),
  ADD KEY `contrato_ibfk_1` (`cedulaEmpleado`),
  ADD KEY `contrato_ibfk_2` (`tipoContrato`);

ALTER TABLE `empleado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cedula`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idEmpleado` (`idEmpleado`),
  ADD KEY `empleado_ibfk_1` (`cargo`),
  ADD KEY `taller` (`taller`);
ALTER TABLE `franquicia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idFranquicia`),
  ADD KEY `ciudad` (`ciudad`);
ALTER TABLE `taller`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idTaller`),
  ADD KEY `Franquicia` (`Franquicia`);
ALTER TABLE `contrato`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contrato_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cedulaEmpleado`) REFERENCES `empleado` (`cedula`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contrato_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tipoContrato`) REFERENCES `tipocontrato` (`idContrato`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `empleado`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `empleado_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cargo`) REFERENCES `cargo` (`idCargo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `empleado_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`taller`) REFERENCES `taller` (`idTaller`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `franquicia`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `franquicia_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ciudad`) REFERENCES `ciudad` (`idCiudad`);
ALTER TABLE `taller`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `taller_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Franquicia`) REFERENCES `franquicia` (`idFranquicia`);
```

When I insert a row in the phpmyadmin panel, the query executes successfully, but if I do the same on my project, the above error appears.

What is the issue?

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that fails and the full error message you get. If error reporting isn't turned on, turn it on. Also add the SQL statement that runs in PHPAdmin